# Reverse proxy in subdirectory can't find static assets

Tags: node.js, nginx, proxy, reverse-proxy, ghost-blog

I'm using Nginx as a reverse proxy to route requests to localhost to my node server, but requests to localhost/blog to a ghost server (a blogging platform)

My Nginx config is like this:

```
server {
    listen 80;

    server_name localhost;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }

    location ^~ /blog {
        rewrite /blog/(.*) /$1 break;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;

        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:2368;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }
}
```

*edit: The reason I'm rewriting the URL with `rewrite /blog/(.*) /$1 break;` is so that the ghost server doesn't get the request to /blog/, which it can't use*

However because ghost, the blogging platform, is designed to be run in the root directory, all static assets fail because they should be going to localhost/**blog**/static/asset/path rather than localhost/static/asset/path:
[image]

Is there any simple solution to this problem? Or do I have to rewrite all the HTML for ghost?

Comment: Why are you removing the blog part so ? Can't you also directly serve the static parts from nginx instead of proxying ? Thats bad for performance.

Comment: Oh sorry I should have explained that. It's because if I don't remove it, the ghost server gets the request to /blog/, which makes no sense to it

Comment: It's a bit confused now, are you saying that you doesn't need the blog part to be removed only for static assets ?

Comment: I need the static assets to go to localhost/blog/asset.css, but the actual HTTP request from the user should be localhost/blog which will then proxy to Ghost without the /blog part

Comment: But there's probably a simpler way to do this, I'm just not sure what it is

Comment: Ok so it's an issue with the backend, won't be much of an help here. However I can suggest you to clean your configuration because the rewrite isn't necessary nor the `^~` operator. Use `location /blog/ { proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:2368/; ... }` instead.

Comment: A bit late to the party but did you find a solution to this?